# Copy row and paste to new table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the code helps me find multiple texts. I want to do the following thing but i get stucked:
Select the entire row of found item
Copy the selected row to new table
Thanks

```
Sub FindMultiItemsInDoc()


Dim objListDoc As Document
  Dim objTargetDoc As Document
  Dim objParaRange As Range, objFoundRange As Range
  Dim objParagraph As Paragraph
  Dim strFileName As String

  strFileName = InputBox("Enter the full name of the list document here:")
 
  Set objTargetDoc = ActiveDocument
  Set objListDoc = Documents.Open(strFileName)
  objTargetDoc.Activate
 
  For Each objParagraph In objListDoc.Paragraphs
    Set objParaRange = objParagraph.Range
    objParaRange.End = objParaRange.End - 1
 
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
 
        '  Find target items.
        With Selection.Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Text = objParaRange
          .MatchWholeWord = True
          .MatchCase = False
          .Execute
        End With
 
  Next objParagraph
End Sub
```

Comment: Missing "End With" for "With Selection". The code does the following: opens a Word file, selects each of the paragraphs in that file and successfully locates them one by one in that file. There's no point in that. What do you really want to find? And where is the table to receive what was copied?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/49409-copy-row-word-table-paste-new-table.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184